# bash how to quote string with quotes

Tags: bash

I want to synchronize some environment variables between scripts.   So, for example, in one script I might have:

```
foo="some value with \"quoted part\""
echo foo="$foo" > tmp.sh;
```

Then in the other script, I want to run `./tmp.sh`.   The issue is with whitespace and quotes.   The tmp.sh script contains:

```
foo=string with "quoted part"
```

Which does not work due to the whitespace.  If I use `\"`'s then it results in:

```
foo="string with "quoted part""
```

which fails because now the space inside the quotes looks like its outside of quotes.  What I want is:

```
foo="string with \"quoted part\""
```

Of course, it should handle already escaped quotes, etc.  Is there any reliable way of quoting a string in bash so it can be used for an assignment later on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `printf '%q'`:

```
$ printf 'foo=%q\n'  "$foo"
foo=some\ value\ with\ \"quoted\ part\"
```

It looks slightly different, but it has the same effect; the backslashes individually quote each character that needs escaping, rather than escaping the entire string unnecessarily (since, for instance, `\v` and `v` are the same character).

Comment: Caveat: `printf %q` will produce a string quoted and/or escaped to comply with bash's parsing rules; the resulting string may not work right in other contexts, or even other shells. So if ./tmp.sh is going to run under bash, this will work perfectly; if it's going to run under something else, there might be problems.